# How change color in IconMode Android?

Tags: android

how can I change in Android Studio the color of the icon Mode? I have declare endIconMode, but I want another color of the icon in xml

```
app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
```

Answer (score 2):

try with this excellent service

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/